# Unable to ping Internal network created by Vagrant

Tags: networking, vagrant, virtualbox

I have been trying to create a internal network using Vagrant with VirtualBox. My host is a MacBook Air and my guests (Ubuntu) cannot ping each other. I have tried various resources online and according to the websites that I have viewed I seem to be doing the right thing. Below is my configuration file for Vagrant:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  # config.vm.provision :salt do |salt|
  # salt.minion_config = "saltstack/etc/minion"
  # salt.run_highstate = true
  # salt.install_type = "git"
  # salt.install_args = "v2014.1.0"
  # salt.verbose = true
end

config.vm.define "web" do |web|
  web.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  web.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.0.2.16", virtualbox__intnet: true, virtualbox__intnet: "intnet"
end

config.vm.define "db" do |db|
db.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
db.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.0.2.17", virtualbox__intnet: true, virtualbox__intnet: "intnet"
end

 config.vm.boot_timeout = 1000
end
```

As you can see I have assigned both ip addresses to my machines. When using the private network option, VirtualBox default is set to host only networking. I would like internal network. So, I added the virtualbox_intnet option to true which enables internal networking. I am using 1.7.2 of vagrant and VirtualBox version is 4.3.30.

Now, I am unable to ping both of these machines from within the guests. What am I doing wrong?

I have visited the main vagrant websites and others including https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=17747

Comment: No sure, because the website actually mentions both. I think the virtual box_intnet: true option specifies that internal networking to be built and virtual box_intnet: "name" tells vagrant to join the machine to the named network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that VirtualBox somehow contains information on the ip address starting from 10.0. So, I changed the ip address from 10.0 to 10.10 and that worked. The ip address for example 10.10.2.17.

Answer (score 0):

After an upgrade of vagrant I had to manually enable the network as it was DOWN (host-system):

```
sudo ip link set up dev vboxnet0
```

After that communication between host and guest worked again.